# Double.parseDouble error java retrieve SOA

Tags: java

I GET SOA STRING USE Double.parseDouble fd.setFdrRate(Double.parseDouble(coreFD.getInterestRate()));  message SOA return 3.7  but screen show 3.7000000000000005 save Database return 3.7 help me to check

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: What is the screen that shows 3.7000000000000005? Where did that number come from

Comment: screen show fields return SOA

Answer (score -1):

`double` [cannot](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) represent the number `3.7` with full precision. You may consider using [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead:

```
new BigDecimal(coreFD.getInterestRate()).toString() // 3.7
```

P.S. *Always* use `BigDecimal` (or similar-purpose class) for storing finance-related numbers.

Comment: I cannot redo the error on my computer. Are you sure it will fix it?

Comment: This is a dup, please try to refer to the original answer for everyone’s benefit. https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/839733

Comment: how to fix? please help me